# Getting search results from Twitter in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, curl, twitter

I'm attempting to put together a little mashup with some twitter APIs.  However, the whole area is new to me (I'm more of an embedded developer dabbling).  And frustratingly, every tutorial I am trying in Php is either out of date, not doing what it claims to do, it or is broken.

Essentially, I just want a nice bit of example code - say, an HTML file, a connection.js for the JQuery magic, and a php file - 'getsearch' which contains the relevant Curl calls to the API to just return the results for a given search term.

Followed the tutorial to the letter at 
http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/using-jquery-php-ajax-with-the-twitter-api/

and even downloaded the guy's code and chucked it on my webserver, but it just seems to sit there.

I'm relatively competent at php and html, but it's the Curl and the JQuery side of things which is new to me, and would appreciate any thoughts, links, or code suggestions.  I've attempted reading the API - but even that seems sparse - and several links are broken to their own tutorials, so that's put me off a bit for now.

Comment: +15 for being lazy and asking SO to write the code for you.

Comment: haha, but no - I just want an example - as I said, a link is fine :) Once I've got *something* working I can build on it happily from there.

Comment: still sounds lazy - you're saying you can't be bothered reading the API or other docs, or finding tutorials that don't have broken links.

Comment: I have spent many hours doing just that, and am doing that in several other windows right now as well. Stackoverflow was a "I wonder if anyone on here has some links that might be of use".

Comment: Saying you put something on your server and "it just seems to sit there" just doesn't sound like much effort went into it. And you didn't just ask for links, but code suggestions. It's okay though, some people don't mind writing code for free. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a working one.

http://papermashup.com/using-the-twitter-api/

This tutorial (or just the php file at http://greenservr.com/projects/twittersearch/TwitterSearch.phps) has the basics including php, jquery and curl to get something back from the twitter API).  Finally have something going, so now can expand and extend :)

Answer (score 0):

check the link http://webhkp.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/twitter-api-search-follow-tweet/. this is a great post i found and really helpful for me. hope you fined something helpful here.